pytest-django: Model class sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label
There have been lots of similar questions, but most of them are irrelevant to pytest. Running manage.py runserver works correctly for me, it only fails with pytest.
When running pytest --collectonly --verbose -n0, pytest fails with the following error:
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.12.6, pytest-8.3.3, pluggy-1.5.0 -- /home/jasongrace2282/repos/website5/.venv/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
django: version: 5.1.3, settings: director.settings (from ini)
rootdir: /home/jasongrace2282/repos/website5/manager
configfile: pyproject.toml
testpaths: director
plugins: django-4.9.0, anyio-4.6.2.post1, xdist-3.6.1
collecting ... collected 1 item / 1 error

<Dir manager>
  <Package director>
    <Dir apps>
      <Package auth>
        <Module tests.py>
          <Function test_password_login>
            Make sure logging in via password on the dev env works.

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
________________ ERROR collecting director/apps/sites/tests.py _________________
director/apps/sites/tests.py:3: in <module>
    from . import parser
director/apps/sites/parser.py:6: in <module>
    from .models import DockerAction, DockerImage, Domain
director/apps/sites/models.py:39: in <module>
    class Site(models.Model):
../.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:134: in __new__
    raise RuntimeError(
E   RuntimeError: Model class sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR director/apps/sites/tests.py - RuntimeError: Model class sites.models.S...
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
====================== 1 test collected, 1 error in 0.17s ======================

My director/apps/sites/apps.py looks like:
class SitesConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "director.apps.sites"

And my settings.INSTALLED_APPS has the following content:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "debug_toolbar",
    "django_browser_reload",
    "django_linear_migrations",
    "social_django",
    "director.apps.auth",
    "director.apps.users",
    "director.apps.sites",
    "heroicons",
]

if DEBUG:
    INSTALLED_APPS += [
        "django_extensions",
    ]

Additionally, my directory structure looks like this
.
├── conftest.py
├── director
│   ├── apps
│   │   ├── auth
│   │   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── models.py
│   │   │   ├── oauth.py
│   │   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   │   └── views.py
│   │   ├── sites
│   │   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   │   ├── 0002_alter_dockerimage_name.py
│   │   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   │   └── max_migration.txt
│   │   │   ├── models.py
│   │   │   ├── parser.py
│   │   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   │   └── views.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── djtypes.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
└── pyproject.toml

With a pytest config of
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = "director.settings"
python_files = ["tests.py", "test_*.py"]


Add 'sites' to INSTALLED_APPS.

You are missing __init__.py in director.apps.

Ah thanks, @MT0, that solved it.

You are missing __init__.py in director.apps .
